# $\frac{10y^{18}}{8y^6}$ simplified to $\frac{5y^{18}}{4y^6}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If anyone can help me  will be eternally grateful. I'm studying indices and I need a clarification about this problem solved by my teacher
$$\frac{10y^{18}}{8y^6}$$

and said , "well, $10$ and $8$ are divisible by $2$ . ." and then she scores out the $10$ and the $8$ and writes $5$ and $4$ respectively.

I havent done maths in over $25$ years and I am about to have a nervous breakdown over this. Where did this division by 2 come up, Please help me with this basic question :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please look up how to format your questions using MathJax. It's very hard to read otherwise

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your question. Can you please format it a little better? See here for a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

For example, are you asking why $$\frac{10y^{18}}{8y^6} = \frac{5y^{18}}{4y^6}?$$

Off topic: You realize this site is full of mathematitians, including math teachers? I don't see what you hope to achieve by talking about "idiot teacher" and how they are an "empty headed fool". If anyone comes off as a fool, it's certainly not the teacher, but a student that is throwing a tantrum.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Very sorry to hear this material is so frustrating. Not that it helps with your question, but (seriously) you might enjoy _A Divine Language_ by Alec Wilkinson.

Comment: I don't mean all math teachers are idiots, i just meant my one is, because she does things with zero explanation.  It's been 25 years since i studied maths but i thought i could do this course.  However, it would have been decent of the college to check this with me first.  Now i'm angry because i've been thrown in the deep end with no preparation or anyone else thinking to check if this course was appropriate for me.  I mean, they run it every year. Surely they should know who it is suitable for. I never passed secondary school maths as a teen and i wanted to prove i could do it now.

Comment: In the hope an adapted extract of _A Divine Language_ is helpful: https://www.theguardian.com/books/2022/aug/07/could-learning-algebra-in-my-60s-make-me-smarter-alec-wilkinson-a-divine-language-extract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* divide both the top and the bottom of a fraction by "any old number", so long as that number isn't zero. You are simply multiplying the fraction by $(1/X)/(1/X)$, which is $1$ - multiplying any number by $1$ yields that same number.

$10/8 = (10/2) / (8/2) = (10/100) / (8/100) = (10/59483) / (8/59483)$

In this particular case, $2$ is the largest common denominator of $10$ and $8$, so choosing to divide by $2$ allows you *simplify* or *reduce* the fraction to the ratio of the smallest integers possible. It directly yields the fraction $5/4$, which cannot be reduced any further.

Simplifying fractions is mostly a matter of convenience, as a simplified fraction represents the *exact same number* that the unsimplified fraction does. It's generally easier to work with simplified fractions since they use the smallest integers possible - most people would prefer to work with $1/7$, for example, rather than $587/4109$, or $85784/600488$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot.

Comment: Hold on, how can you have 10 eighths?  You can only have four fourths, five fifths and so on, you can only have eight eighths . . . not 10.

Answer (score 3):

You are always free to divide or even multiply both the numerator and denominator by a **NON ZERO NUMBER**

You are even allowed to divide them by a number of your choice except $0$

Since $HCF(10,8)$ is $2$, Your teacher has divided both of them by $2$ to make things simpler :)

Learn basic operations , fractions and their properties before you attend your next class !

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps a lot.

Comment: Good to know it helped you :)

Comment: Hold on, how can you have 10 eighths? You can only have four fourths, five fifths and so on, you can only have eight eighths . . . not 10.

Comment: What do you mean? @Cookies

Comment: I mean the fraction says 10 over 8, which I read as 10 pieces from a total of 8.  8f 8 slice a cake 8 ways I can't have 9 or 10 pieces right? So, why does the fraction say 10 over 8?

Comment: The fraction 10 over 8 is an improper fraction 10/8 can be seen as 1+1/4 which is 1 full cake and a quarter a a cake @Cookies, You can actually see that 5/4 can also be written as 1+1/4 :)